# "CIDR is invalid" when creating an Amazon VPC via AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

I'm working with the [PCI DSS on AWS - Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/compliance-pci/) template. It works without issue - but when I edit the ProductionVPC to custom IPs of my own choosing, the stack fails. My subnets are as follows:

```
(MAIN) ProductionVPC: 172.21.32.0/19
pDMZSubnetACIDR: 172.21.48.0/23
pDMZSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.50.0/23
pAppPrivateSubnetACIDR: 172.21.32.0/21
pAppPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.40.0/21
pDBPrivateSubnetACIDR: 172.21.52.0/23
pDBPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.54.0/23
```

When I run this, the stack fails and I see a few of the following errors for the above subnets as seen below:

> The CIDR '172.21.52.0/23' is invalid. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet.Range; Request ID: d1998b65-396e-48e7-863a-2c1e0919fbff; Proxy: null)

Is there something wrong with my subnet choices? I don't see any overlap but I might be missing something.

UPDATE: I'm adding the entire code snippets. The original Quickstart template is here:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Provides nesting for required stacks to deploy a baseline architecure to support PCI compliance. (qs-1qtdd1c6i)
Metadata:
  Stack:
    Value: 0
  VersionDate:
    Value: 20190805
  Identifier:
    Value: main
  Input:
    Description: Input of all required parameters in nested stacks
  Output:
    Description: N/A
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: 'VPC Configuration'
        Parameters:
          - VPCTenancy
          - AvailabilityZoneA
          - AvailabilityZoneB
      - Label:
          default: "EC2 Configuration"
        Parameters:
          - EC2KeyPairBastion
          - EC2KeyPair
      - Label:
          default: AWS Quick Start Configuration
        Parameters:
          - QSS3BucketName
          - QSS3BucketRegion
          - QSS3KeyPrefix
      - Label:
          default: IAM Password Policy
        Parameters:
          - MaxPasswordAge
          - MinPasswordLength
          - PasswordHistory
          - RequireLowercaseChars
          - RequireNumbers
          - RequireSymbols
          - RequireUppercaseChars
      - Label:
          default: Database configuration
        Parameters:
          - DBUsername
          - DBPassword
    ParameterLabels:
      EC2KeyPairBastion:
        default: Existing SSH key for the bastion instance
      EC2KeyPair:
        default: Existing SSH key for other instances
      AvailabilityZoneA:
        default: First Availability Zone
      AvailabilityZoneB:
        default: Second Availability zone
      VPCTenancy:
        default: Instance tenancy
      QSS3BucketName:
        default: Quick Start S3 bucket name
      QSS3BucketRegion:
        default: Quick Start S3 bucket region
      QSS3KeyPrefix:
        default: Quick Start S3 key prefix
      MaxPasswordAge:
        default: Maximum password age
      MinPasswordLength:
        default: Minimum password length
      PasswordHistory:
        default: Previous passwords retained
      RequireLowercaseChars:
        default: Lowercase characters required
      RequireNumbers:
        default: Number required
      RequireSymbols:
        default: Symbol required
      RequireUppercaseChars:
        default: Uppercase character required
      DBUsername:
        default: Database user name
      DBPassword:
        default: Database password

Parameters:
  EC2KeyPairBastion:
    Description: The SSH key pair in your account to use for the bastion host login. This is one of the keys that you created in the pre-deployment steps.
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  EC2KeyPair:
    Description: The SSH key pair in your account to use for all other EC2 instance logins. This is one of the keys that you created in the pre-deployment steps.
      logins
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  AvailabilityZoneA:
    Description: The name of Availability Zone 1.
    Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name
  AvailabilityZoneB:
    Description: The name of Availability Zone 2. This must be different from the name of the first Availability Zone.
    Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name
  MaxPasswordAge:
    Type: 'Number'
    Description: 'Maximum age for passwords, in number of days.'
    Default: 90
    ConstraintDescription: '(90-365 days)'
    MinValue: 1
    MaxValue: 90
  MinPasswordLength:
    Type: 'Number'
    Description: 'Minimum password length.'
    Default: 7
    ConstraintDescription: '(8-128 characters)'
    MinValue: 7
    MaxValue: 128
  PasswordHistory:
    Type: 'Number'
    Description: 'Number of previous passwords to remember.'
    Default: 4
    ConstraintDescription: '(1-24 passwords)'
    MinValue: 4
    MaxValue: 24
  RequireLowercaseChars:
    Type: 'String'
    Description: 'Password requirement of at least one lowercase character.'
    Default: 'True'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'True'
      - 'False'
  RequireNumbers:
    Type: 'String'
    Description: 'Password requirement of at least one number.'
    Default: 'True'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'True'
      - 'False'
  RequireSymbols:
    Type: 'String'
    Description: 'Password requirement of at least one nonalphanumeric character.'
    Default: 'True'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'True'
      - 'False'
  RequireUppercaseChars:
    Type: 'String'
    Description: 'Password requirement of at least one uppercase character.'
    Default: 'True'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'True'
      - 'False'
  VPCTenancy:
    Description: The tenancy attribute for the instances launched into the VPC. If unsure, leave as default.
    Type: String
    Default: default
    AllowedValues:
      - default
      - dedicated
  QSS3BucketName:
    AllowedPattern: ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*$
    ConstraintDescription: Quick Start bucket name can include numbers, lowercase
      letters, uppercase letters, periods (.), and hyphens (-). It cannot start or
      end with a hyphen (-). If you are unsure, do not change this value.
    Default: aws-quickstart
    Description: S3 bucket name for the Quick Start assets. Quick Start bucket name
      can include numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and hyphens (-).
      It cannot start or end with a hyphen (-). If you are unsure, do not change this value.
    Type: String
  QSS3BucketRegion:
    Default: 'us-east-1'
    Description: The AWS Region where the Quick Start S3 bucket (QSS3BucketName) is hosted. When using your own bucket, you must specify this value.
    Type: String
  QSS3KeyPrefix:
    AllowedPattern: ^[0-9a-zA-Z-/]*$
    ConstraintDescription: Quick Start key prefix can include numbers, lowercase letters,
      uppercase letters, hyphens (-), and forward slash (/). If you are unsure, do not change this value.
    Default: quickstart-compliance-pci/
    Description: S3 key prefix for the Quick Start assets. Quick Start key prefix
      can include numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, hyphens (-), and
      forward slash (/). If you are unsure, do not change this value.
    Type: String
  DBUsername:
    Default: 'admin'
    Description: User name for connecting to the database instance.
    Type: String
  DBPassword:
    AllowedPattern: ^(?=^.{8,255}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[@/"']).*$
    ConstraintDescription: "Min 8 chars. Must include 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 (non / @ \" ') symbol"
    Description: Password for connecting to the database instance.
    Type: String
    NoEcho: True
Mappings:
  CustomVariables:
    vResourceEnvironmentTagKey:
      Value: Environment
    vResourceEnvironmentTagValue:
      Value: development
  Instances:
    ap-northeast-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    ap-northeast-2:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    ap-south-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    ap-southeast-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    ap-southeast-2:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    ca-central-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    eu-central-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    eu-west-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    eu-west-2:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    sa-east-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    us-east-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    us-east-2:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    us-west-1:
      InstanceType: m4.large
    us-west-2:
      InstanceType: m4.large
      ConfigRules: 'true'
      Glacier: 'true'
  AWSAMIRegionMap:
    ap-northeast-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-02ddf94e5edc8e904
    ap-northeast-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-0ecd78c22823e02ef
    ap-south-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-05695932c5299858a
    ap-southeast-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-043afc2b8b6cfba5c
    ap-southeast-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-01393ce9a3ca55d67
    ca-central-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-0fa94ecf2fef3420b
    eu-central-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-0ba441bdd9e494102
    eu-west-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-0e61341fa75fcaa18
    eu-west-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-050b8344d77081f4b
    sa-east-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-05b7dbc290217250d
    us-east-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-0e2ff28bfb72a4e45
    us-east-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-0998bf58313ab53da
    us-gov-west-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-ffa61d9e
    us-gov-east-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-slkdf
    us-west-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-021bb9f371690f97a
    us-west-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-079f731edfe27c29c
Conditions:
  UsingDefaultBucket: !Equals [!Ref QSS3BucketName, 'aws-quickstart']
  LaunchAsDedicatedInstance:
    !Equals
    - !Ref VPCTenancy
    - dedicated
Resources:
  IAMPasswordPolicy:
    Type: 'Custom::IAMPolicyResource'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt IAMPasswordPolicyResource.Arn
      Region: !Ref "AWS::Region"

  IAMPasswordPolicyResource:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Runtime: python3.7
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt IAMPasswordPolicyResourceExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import boto3
          from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
          import json
          import cfnresponse

          iam = boto3.client("iam")

          # Lambda entry point
          def lambda_handler(event, context):

            if event['RequestType'] == 'Create' or event['RequestType'] == 'Update':
              res, reason = update_policy()
            elif event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
              res, reason = delete_policy()
            else:
              res = False
              reason = "Unknown operation: " + event['RequestType']
            responseData = {}
            responseData['Reason'] = reason
            if res:
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
            else:
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, responseData)

          def update_policy():
            try:

              response = iam.update_account_password_policy(
                  AllowUsersToChangePassword=True,
                  HardExpiry=False,
                  MaxPasswordAge=${MaxPasswordAge},
                  MinimumPasswordLength=${MinPasswordLength},
                  RequireLowercaseCharacters=${RequireLowercaseChars},
                  RequireNumbers=${RequireNumbers},
                  RequireSymbols=${RequireSymbols},
                  RequireUppercaseCharacters=${RequireUppercaseChars},
                  PasswordReusePrevention=${PasswordHistory})

              return(True, response)
            except Exception as e:
              return (False, "Cannot update policy: " + str(e))

          def delete_policy():
            try:

              policy = iam.get_account_password_policy()
              response = iam.delete_account_password_policy()
              return (True, response)
            except Exception as e:
              return (False, "Cannot delete policy: " + str(e))

  IAMPasswordPolicyResourceExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: IAMPasswordCreatorPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy
                  - iam:UpdateAccountPasswordPolicy
                  - iam:DeleteAccountPasswordPolicy
                Resource: "*"
  IamTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/templates/iam.template'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
  ProductionVpcTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/templates/vpc-production.template'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
      Parameters:
        pRegionAZ1Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneA
        pRegionAZ2Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneB
        pProductionVPCName: Production VPC
        pBastionSSHCIDR: 0.0.0.0/0
        pDMZSubnetACIDR: 10.100.10.0/24
        pDMZSubnetBCIDR: 10.100.20.0/24
        pManagementCIDR: 10.10.0.0/16
        pAppPrivateSubnetACIDR: 10.100.96.0/21
        pAppPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 10.100.119.0/21
        pDBPrivateSubnetACIDR: 10.100.194.0/21
        pDBPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 10.100.212.0/21
        pVPCTenancy: !Ref VPCTenancy
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref QSS3BucketName
        QSS3BucketRegion: !Ref QSS3BucketRegion
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Sub ${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/
  ManagementVpcTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/templates/vpc-management.template'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
      Parameters:
        pProductionVPC:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rVPCProduction
        pRouteTableProdPrivate:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rRouteTableProdPrivate
        pRouteTableProdPublic:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rRouteTableProdPublic
        pProductionCIDR: 10.100.0.0/16
        pBastionSSHCIDR: 0.0.0.0/0
        pManagementCIDR: 10.10.0.0/16
        pManagementDMZSubnetACIDR: 10.10.1.0/24
        pManagementDMZSubnetBCIDR: 10.10.2.0/24
        pManagementPrivateSubnetACIDR: 10.10.20.0/24
        pManagementPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 10.10.30.0/24
        pManagementVPCName: Management VPC
        pEC2KeyPairBastion: !Ref EC2KeyPairBastion
        pEC2KeyPair: !Ref EC2KeyPair
        pVPCTenancy: !Ref VPCTenancy
        pBastionAmi:
          !FindInMap
          - AWSAMIRegionMap
          - !Ref AWS::Region
          - AMZNLINUXHVM
        pRegionAZ1Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneA
        pRegionAZ2Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneB
        pBastionInstanceType:
          !If
          - LaunchAsDedicatedInstance
          - m4.large
          - t2.small
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref QSS3BucketName
        QSS3BucketRegion: !Ref QSS3BucketRegion
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Sub ${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/
  ConfigRulesTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    DependsOn:
      - IamTemplate
      - ProductionVpcTemplate
      - ManagementVpcTemplate
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/templates/config-rules.template'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
      Parameters:
        pRequiredTagKey:
          !FindInMap
          - CustomVariables
          - vResourceEnvironmentTagKey
          - Value
  DatabaseTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    DependsOn: ProductionVpcTemplate
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}templates/database.template.yaml'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      Parameters:
        ProductionVPC:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rVPCProduction
        DBPrivateSubnetA:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rAppPrivateSubnetA
        DBPrivateSubnetB:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rAppPrivateSubnetB
        RegionAZ1Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneA
        RegionAZ2Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneB
        DBName: examplewordpress
        DBUser: !Ref DBUsername
        DBPassword: !Ref DBPassword
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref QSS3BucketName
        QSS3BucketRegion: !Ref QSS3BucketRegion
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Ref QSS3KeyPrefix
  ApplicationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}templates/application-ssl.template.yaml'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 30
      Parameters:
        AvailabilityZoneA: !Ref AvailabilityZoneA
        AvailabilityZoneB: !Ref AvailabilityZoneB
        pEC2KeyPair: !Ref EC2KeyPair
        pProductionCIDR: 10.100.0.0/16
        pManagementCIDR: 10.10.0.0/16
        pProductionVPC: !GetAtt ProductionVpcTemplate.Outputs.rVPCProduction
        pDMZSubnetA: !GetAtt ProductionVpcTemplate.Outputs.rDMZSubnetA
        pDMZSubnetB: !GetAtt ProductionVpcTemplate.Outputs.rDMZSubnetB
        pAppPrivateSubnetA: !GetAtt ProductionVpcTemplate.Outputs.rAppPrivateSubnetA
        pAppPrivateSubnetB: !GetAtt ProductionVpcTemplate.Outputs.rAppPrivateSubnetB
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref QSS3BucketName
        QSS3BucketRegion: !Ref QSS3BucketRegion
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Ref QSS3KeyPrefix
        pDBHost: !GetAtt DatabaseTemplate.Outputs.AuroraClusterEndpoint
        pDBName: examplewordpress
        pDBUser: !Ref DBUsername
        pDBPassword: !Ref DBPassword
Outputs:
  TemplateType:
    Value: Standard Architecture
  TemplateVersion:
    Value: 2.5
  BastionIP:
    Description: Use this IP via SSH to connect to Bastion Instance
    Value:
      !GetAtt
      - ManagementVpcTemplate
      - Outputs.rBastionInstanceIP
```

...And my updated template is below. I only updated the ProductionVPCTemplate and ManagementVPCTemplate CIDR blocks, so I only included those two resources. You can copy and paste into the original template above. Note that the Management VPC CIDR blocks work fine - if I add those and leave everything else untouched, the stack creates. But if I add only the Production VPC CIDR block, then it fails - so I have it narrowed down to Production VPC.

```
ProductionVpcTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/templates/vpc-production.template'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
      Parameters:
        pRegionAZ1Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneA
        pRegionAZ2Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneB
        pProductionVPCName: Production VPC
        pBastionSSHCIDR: 0.0.0.0/0
        pDMZSubnetACIDR: 172.21.48.0/23
        pDMZSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.50.0/23
        pManagementCIDR: 172.21.0.0/21
        pAppPrivateSubnetACIDR: 172.21.32.0/21
        pAppPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.40.0/21
        pDBPrivateSubnetACIDR: 172.21.52.0/23
        pDBPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.54.0/23
        pVPCTenancy: !Ref VPCTenancy
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref QSS3BucketName
        QSS3BucketRegion: !Ref QSS3BucketRegion
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Sub ${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/
  ManagementVpcTemplate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL:
        !Sub
          - 'https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/templates/vpc-management.template'
          - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
            S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
      Parameters:
        pProductionVPC:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rVPCProduction
        pRouteTableProdPrivate:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rRouteTableProdPrivate
        pRouteTableProdPublic:
          !GetAtt
          - ProductionVpcTemplate
          - Outputs.rRouteTableProdPublic
        pProductionCIDR: 172.21.32.0/19
        pBastionSSHCIDR: 0.0.0.0/0
        pManagementCIDR: 172.21.0.0/21
        pManagementDMZSubnetACIDR: 172.21.0.0/23
        pManagementDMZSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.2.0/23
        pManagementPrivateSubnetACIDR: 172.21.4.0/23
        pManagementPrivateSubnetBCIDR: 172.21.6.0/23
        pManagementVPCName: Management VPC
        pEC2KeyPairBastion: !Ref EC2KeyPairBastion
        pEC2KeyPair: !Ref EC2KeyPair
        pVPCTenancy: !Ref VPCTenancy
        pBastionAmi:
          !FindInMap
          - AWSAMIRegionMap
          - !Ref AWS::Region
          - AMZNLINUXHVM
        pRegionAZ1Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneA
        pRegionAZ2Name: !Ref AvailabilityZoneB
        pBastionInstanceType:
          !If
          - LaunchAsDedicatedInstance
          - m4.large
          - t2.small
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref QSS3BucketName
        QSS3BucketRegion: !Ref QSS3BucketRegion
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Sub ${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-compliance-common/
```

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of your previous post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114121/why-is-this-modified-cloudformation-quickstart-template-vpc-failing

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I meant to delete the last post, as I thought it was too wordy and could be simplified.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a **minimal example** of  template that generates this error so that we can try to reproduce your situation. The template you linked from your original question (that I have inserted here) does not have any parameters asking for CIDRs.

Comment: Ok, I added the original template along with the only portion of it that I edited. So someone can use the original as the control factor, then experiment with the subnet changes I made.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still confusing how we can reproduce your situation. Could you please explain (or provide) exactly what we should do to reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 0):

> http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=172.21.32.0&mask1=19&mask2=21

This tool will move IP based on the input